# Como resolver o aviso "No appenders could be found for logger"?

Tags: java, jsf, log4j

Estou tentando configurar o Log4j no meu projeto com JSF. Segui todos os passos de um [tutorial que achei no Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hpnTIezZy0). Porém, está sendo lançada a seguinte mensagem:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (br.com.hidros.control.beans.ControleBean).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Estou usando o `log4j-1.2.17.jar`.

O meu arquivo `log4j.properties` já está no console da pasta WEB-INF e na minha classe eu fiz isso:

```
public class ControleBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ControleBean.class);
```

E nos *catchs*:

```
catch (ConnectException ex) {
    contarTentativas();
    System.out.println("ConnectException de ControleBean.verificarReles(Placa placa) (PLACA ="+placa.getIpPlaca()+")");
    log.info("ConnectException de ControleBean.verificarReles(Placa placa)");
    log.debug(ex, ex);          
}
```

Meu arquivo `log4j.properties` está dessa forma:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, R, O

log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=log4j.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB

log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.O.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.O.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O arquivo `log4j.properties` deve ser colocado na pasta `WEB-INF/classes` da sua aplicação. Se está somente na `WEB-INF` ou em outro diretório não vai funcionar.

Isso está documentado no [manual do Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).